# What does comma mean in this Groovy Closure?

Tags: groovy

I found the following expression:

```
 { i -> module BookRow, $("table#book-results tbody tr", i) }
```

in [Modelling repeating structures with Geb page objects article](http://adhockery.blogspot.ru/2010/11/modelling-repeating-structures-with-geb.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside this Groovy closure, you have a call to a `module` method that takes two arguments: `BookRow` and `$("table#book-results tbody tr", i)`. Groovy actually allows to omit parentheses for top-level statements, and here, the comma separator actually separates the two arguments of this `module` method call.

ie. `foo a, b` is equivalent to `foo(a, b)`.

If you wanted to separate two statements on the same line, you'd use semi-colons: `foo(); bar()`.